# Render view in modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, modal-dialog, render

I am trying to render a view in a modal but I can't figure out how to do this.

I tried a workaround by creating a partial view but could not trigger a method in the home controller (on load form).

I was wondering, is it possible to have a partial view triggering a method in the controller or should I changed it to a casual view (which I did not manage to show it)?

view:

```
@model IEnumerable<CharityProject.Models.UserInfos>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "SelectAddress";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Select Address</h2>

<p>
    @* <input type="button" value="Add New Address" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "UserInfos")'" />*@
    <input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="Add New Address" class="btn btn-default">
</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cities)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Area)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.POB)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNo)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNo2)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsDefault)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cities.CityName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Area)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.POB)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNo)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNo2)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsDefault)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">


    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
                **@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("CreateAddress", new UserInfos());}**
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uiactions="@Url.Action("Create", "UserInfos")" formmethod="post">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Home controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateAddress()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Use Javascript to do an ajax request to show/invoke methods on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used ,Net Core as of yet, still in the learning process, but from what I remember from the classic MVC approach(.NET),

Create a an AJAX method that will send data to the controller using

> @Html.Action/@Html.ActionLink/@Url.Action, etc

The partial View should have access to the main view's Model object ( if you do a @Html.Partial)

Comment: i made it with ajax but when i submit the form redirects to the actual page and closes the popup window.

Comment: no because the popup autoclose on submit even if the model has error.

Comment: The reason the pop closes is probably because the ajax call you used ends with a close modal statement, can you post the method you used and the error you get?

Comment: Have a look this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397996/popup-auto-close-after-submit)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET Core you should use View Components.

Create a class deriving from ViewComponent containing the InvokeAsync method:

```
public class AddressViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Put your view in this path structure "/Views/Shared/Components/Address/Default.cshtml".

Then, to render the component in your modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Address")
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting this error on   @{ await Component.InvokeAsync("CreateAddress" }.  The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CharityProject.Models.UserInfos]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'CharityProject.Models.UserInfos'.

Comment: Check the model in the view of your CreateAddress component, probably it's something like **@model UserInfos** but your InvokeAsync method is returning a list instead of a single object.