# Popup not returning values in form with errors

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1, C#, MVC.
I have a modal popup and when I submit the form with ajax not showing the errors of the model (required fields etc) on the same popup window, it just shows the modal like the photo below without any changes.

What I am doing wrong and how i can show the required fields if not completed after post pack?

**I think the problem is modal popup is not refreshing.**

before post back and after post back:

[image]

Popup View:

```
@model CharityProject.Models.UserInfos

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";

    Layout = "";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<h4>UserInfos</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="CreateAddress" id="createform">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ApplicationUserId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="ApplicationUserId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ApplicationUserId"></select>
                </div>
            }

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CitiesId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="CitiesId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CitiesId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Area" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Area" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Area" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Address" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Address" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Address" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="POB" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="POB" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="POB" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PhoneNo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PhoneNo" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PhoneNo2" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PhoneNo2" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNo2" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input asp-for="IsDefault" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsDefault)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#createform").submit(function (e) {
            debugger;
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log('Doing ajax submit');

            var formAction = $(this).attr("action");



            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: formAction,
                async: true,
                data: $('#createform').serialize() ,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (content) {
                    debugger;
                    $('#myModal').find("div.modal-body").html(content);
                    // $('#myModal').modal("hide");
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    debugger;
                    var msg = e;
                }
            });

        });
    })
    </script>
```

Parent View:

```
@model IEnumerable<CharityProject.Models.UserInfos>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "SelectAddress";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Select Address</h2>

<p>
    @* <input type="button" value="Add New Address" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "UserInfos")'" />*@
    <input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="Add New Address" class="btn btn-default" id="showthis">
</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cities)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Area)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.POB)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNo)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNo2)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsDefault)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cities.CityName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Area)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.POB)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNo)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNo2)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsDefault)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">


    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close"  aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $('#showthis').click(function (e) {


            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'CreateAddress',
                async: false,
                success: function (content) {
                    $('#myModal').find("div.modal-body").html(content);
                },
                error: function (e) { }
            });
        });

    })
</script>
```

Controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAddress([Bind("Id,CitiesId,Area,Address,POB,PhoneNo,PhoneNo2,IsDefault,ApplicationUserId")] UserInfos userInfos)
        {
            var userid = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
            if (!User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                userInfos.ApplicationUserId = userid;
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(userInfos);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                // return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                return Json(new { status = "success" });
            }
            ViewData["CitiesId"] = new SelectList(_context.Cities, "Id", "CityName", userInfos.CitiesId);
            ViewData["ApplicationUserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users.Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(u => u.Role).Where(o => o.UserRoles.All(r => r.Role.Name == "Customer")), "Id", "Email", userInfos.ApplicationUserId);
           // return View(userInfos);
            return Json(new { content = userInfos });
        }
```

Comment: how is the page redirecting? from what I can see, the modal's body should be set correctly, though I do not see what you do with the errors though, only that they are set to a local variable. Could you hit F12 on your browser, check the network tab and see what the Ajax method returns when there is an error and maybe post it here?

Comment: I don't get any error when i hit F12 on browser. Then problem is in my model the return. This is what i have to change but i don't know what should be i quess .

Comment: I found that I cant get Model of the form with the values on javascript on this line  var infoForm = @Model; . Any idea?

Comment: var data = JSON.stringify( $(form).serializeArray() ); try that, use form as ur form

Comment: I have update my question with new info and screen shots. Please have a look.

Comment: Press F12 on your browser and check the network TAB, click send and then check what you sent to the server

Comment: The problem was  $('#myModal').find("div.modal-body").html(content); i changed it to  $(**'#createform'**).find("div.modal-body").html(content); and now keeps the same form on popup but still not showing the errors. I debug the code and i am sending back the model to view. I am not getting any error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187443/discussion-between-marios-and-mahlatse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing 2 JS references files from the page because I didn't added layout.

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Also if you want to take the Model of the form you can do it with

```
var data = JSON.stringify( $(form).serializeArray() );
```